# count points for elements in array with javascript switch case statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, switch-statement

I am creating a jackpot game that generates an array based on haw many times a given image appears. and then calculates how many 0(card not used),1(different cards),2(2 same cards),3(same cards),4(4 same cards),5 (5 same cards) occurs  the array (aPunten) looks like this:

```
8,5,0,0,0,0
```

this means 8 times 0, 5 times 1, 0 times 2 (pair), 0 times 3(trips), 0 times 4 (quads), 0 times 5

Now i need to distribute a score to these values and that's where I am stuck. 
I would like to loop trough the array(aPunten) and use a switch case to distribute the points.

Points awarded for combinations:

```
5 equal cards= +50
4 equal cards= +25
3 equal cards + 1 pair  = +20
3 equal cards= +10
pair + pair = +5
pair= +2
5 different cards= +0
```

I hope someone can put me on the right track here

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out myself, this probably isn't the best way to do it but it works.
Feel free to show me a shorter version of this.

```
for (var k = 0; k < aPunten.length; k++) {

        switch (k) {

            case 0:
                combo = "Jammer u hebt verloren...";
                break;
            case 1:
                combo = "Jammer u hebt verloren...";
                break;
            case 2:

                if (aPunten[k] == 1) {
                    x += 2;
                    paar += 1;
                    combo = "1 paar!!";
                }
                if (aPunten[k] == 2) {
                    x += 5;
                    paar += 2;
                    combo = "2 paar!!";
                }
                break;
            case 3:

                if (aPunten[k] == 1) {
                    if (paar == 0) {
                        combo = "3 dezelfde!!";
                        x += 10;
                    } else if (paar == 1) {
                        combo = "3 dezelfde en 1 paar!!";
                        x += 20
                    }
                }

                break;
            case 4:

                if (aPunten[k] == 1) {
                    combo = "4 dezelfde !!";
                    x += 25;
                }
                break;
            case 5:

                if (aPunten[k] == 1) {
                    combo = "JAAACKKKKPOOOOOT!!";
                    x += 50;
                }
                break;
        }

    }
```